# Approximating $\int \log\big[1+\sin^2(t)\big]\,dt$

Tags: definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals, approximation

On yesterday, a now closed [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3977557/how-should-i-calculate-this-type-of-integration) asked for a while how to compute the antiderivative
$$I=\int \log\big[1+\sin^2(t)\big]\,dt$$ which, as given by a CAS, is just awful (see @Forester's comment and @Turing's answer). During the time the question was open, I tried on my side and gave up since being unable to find anything simpler.

Then, I tried to approximate the integrand since we just need a good representation of it for $0 \leq t \leq \frac \pi 2$ because of the symmetries and periodicity. What I am proposing is a polynomial function matching the function and its first and second derivative values at a minimum number of data points. For the time being, I chose $t=0$, $t=\frac \pi 4$ and $t=\frac \pi 2$. The final result is
$$f(t)=\log\big[1+\sin^2(t)\big]\sim t^2+\frac 19 \sum_{n=3}^8 \frac{a_n}{\pi^n} t^n=g(t)$$ the $a_n$'s being
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
n & a_n & \frac{a_n}{9\pi^n}\\
 3 & -768 \pi -217 \pi ^2-22608 \log (2)+18432 \log (3) &         +0.087806356 \\
 4 & 7680 \pi +1940 \pi ^2+286416 \log (2)-221184 \log (3) &      -1.360303642 \\
 5 & -27648 \pi -8500 \pi ^2-1501632 \log (2)+1105920 \log (3) &  +1.225383826 \\
 6 & 43008 \pi +19568 \pi ^2+3960576 \log (2)-2801664 \log (3) &  -0.512958585 \\
 7 & -24576 \pi -22720 \pi ^2-5170176 \log (2)+3538944 \log (3) & +0.102611702 \\
 8 & 10496 \pi ^2+2654208 \log (2)-1769472 \log (3) &             -0.007207813
\end{array}
\right)$$

About the norm
$$\Phi=\int_0^{\frac \pi 2} \big[f(t)-g(t)\big]^2 \, dt=1.79 \times 10^{-8}$$ while the beautiful approximation
$$\sin(t) \simeq \frac{16 (\pi -t) t}{5 \pi ^2-4 (\pi -t) t}\qquad \text{for} \qquad 0\leq t\leq\pi$$ would lead to  $\Phi=8.74 \times 10^{-7}$ (almost $50$ times larger).

From this
$$J(x)=\int_0^x \log\big[1+\sin^2(t)\big]\,dt\sim \frac 13 x^3+\frac 19 \sum_{n=3}^8 \frac{a_n}{(n+1)\,\pi^n} x^{n+1}$$

As a test
$$J\left(\frac{\pi }{2}\right)=\frac{\pi }{181440}\left(432 (128 \log (3)-87 \log (2))-55 \pi ^2 \right)\approx 0.591383$$ to be compared to the exact value
$$ \pi \log\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)\approx 0.591331$$ recalled by @projectilemotion in comments.

**My questions**

> Without adding more terms, could it be possible to improve the approximation ? Would changes of base points could have a significant impact (if yes, how to optimize them ?)

> Would, by chance, be known (in a simple form) the exact values of the integrals
> $$K_n=\int_{-\frac \pi n}^{\frac \pi n} \log\big[1+\sin^2(t)\big]\,dt$$ beside the case of $n=2$ ? If there were, I suppose that much better approximations could be done.

Comment: Let $f(a)=\int_{-\pi/n}^{\pi/n}\log(a+\sin^2t)\,dt$. Then $\displaystyle f(a)=4\int\frac{\arctan(b\tan\frac\pi n)}{1-b^2}\,db$ where $b=\sqrt{1+1/a}$ and $K_n=f(1)$.

Comment: If we want some simple form of approximation, e.g., polynomial, here is one: \begin{align}
\int_0^x \ln(1 + \sin^2 t) \mathrm{d} t &\approx
0.0007816865900x - 0.01981190300x^2 + 0.4408790493x^3\\
&\qquad - 0.2311179794x^4 + 0.03526708854x^5.
\end{align} The largest absolute error is less than $0.00015$.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire. Thanks. I tried Feynman trick for both $\log(a+\sin^2t)$ and $\log(1+a\sin^2t)$ but I arrived to monsters I am unable to simplify. Any idea ? Cheers :-)

Comment: @RiverLi. Thanks for the effort ! However, I would like you check your regression since, as shown below, I have quite different results. I used $1000$ equally spaced values of $x$ between $0$ and $\frac \pi 2$ and obtained $(R^2=0.9999999897)$ the following results (see next comment). Maximum error $=0.00006$.

Comment: $$\begin{array}{clclclclc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{Confidence Interval} \\
 a & +0.00240462 & 0.00003239 & \{+0.00234106,+0.00246818\}  \\
 b & -0.02970854 & 0.00017028 & \{-0.03004269,-0.02937439\}  \\
 c & +0.46029551 & 0.00030906 & \{+0.45968903,+0.46090198\}  \\
 d & -0.24616488 & 0.00023124 & \{-0.24661866,-0.24571110\}  \\
 e & +0.03927511 & 0.00006100 & \{+0.03915541,+0.03939482\}  \\
\end{array}$$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I made use of the minimax approximation of $\ln(1 + \sin^2 t)$ on $[0, \pi/2]$. We can do it in Maple: with(numapprox); minimax(ln(1+sin(t)^2), t = 0 .. (1/2)*Pi, 4).The output is $0.00078168659 - 0.0396238060t + 1.322637148t^2-0.9244719176t^3+0.1763354427t^4$.

Comment: @RiverLi. This explains that ! May I confess that I do not like to use the minimax approximation. Moreover, what I did fit was the integral and not the integrand. Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici If you want $\int_0^x \ln(1 + \sin^2 t) \mathrm{d} t \approx a_3x^3 + a_2x^2 + a_1x + a_0$ for example, it may be not easy to find the coefficients.

Comment: @RiverLi. No problem since the numerical integration is very fast even for high accuracy and then whatever method you want. Now, I think that all is clear. Thanks again.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Nice. By the way, sometimes the form of approximation looks unusual (but simple), for example, (I saw it in MSE) the following approximation
is quite good:
$\int_0^{\pi} (\frac{\sin x}{x})^k \mathrm{d} x \approx a b^{1/k} k^{-c} + d$
where $a = 2.173, b = 0.8536, c = 0.4982, d = 0.002996$.

Answer (score 5):

A physicist's point of view. So i'm trying to keep things as simple as possible.
(I'm using $\ln x$ rather than $\log x$).

The first step is to choose an approximate, simple analytical expression for $\ln(1+y)$ in $y\in[0,1]:$

$$\ln(1+y)\approx\frac{\ln 2}{131}y(20y^2-75y+186) $$

Now, set $y=\sin^2t$

$$\ln(1+\sin^2t)\approx\frac{\ln 2}{131}(131+35\cos^2t+20\cos^4t)\sin^2t$$

Next, integrate this expression with respect to $t$ over the interval $[0, x]$ $x\in[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$ and denote the result $I(x)$

A closed-form expression can be obtained for $I(x)$ but it is a little bit messy. But for $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$ we obtain:

$$I\left(\frac{\pi }{2}\right)=\frac{569}{2096}\pi\ln 2$$

Absolute error from exact value is about $0.0002$

It is about an order of magnitude more inaccurate than Claude's result $J\left(\frac{\pi }{2}\right)$ but this is the price we have to pay for simplicity.

Comment: Nice, although the closed form expression is not very simple.

Comment: You inspired me ! Thanks and $\to +1$ for sure. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 4):

After @Martin Gales's, I think that I had an idea.

Rewrite
$$\log\big[1+\sin^2(t)\big]=\log\Bigg[\frac {1+ \frac{2 \sin ^2(t)}{5-\cos (2 t)}} {1- \frac{2 \sin ^2(t)}{5-\cos (2 t)}}\Bigg]$$

and use
$$\log \left(\frac{1+a}{1-a}\right)=2 \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$$ to make
$$\log\big[1+\sin^2(t)\big]=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{4^{n+1}}{2n+1} \Bigg[\frac{ \sin ^2(t)}{5-\cos (2 t)}\Bigg]^{2n+1}$$
$$\int\log\big[1+\sin^2(t)\big]\,dt=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{4^{n+1}}{2n+1} \int\Bigg[\frac{ \sin ^2(t)}{5-\cos (2 t)}\Bigg]^{2n+1}dt$$
All these integrals can be analytically computed (an example [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5BSin%5Bx%5D%5E22%2F%285+-+Cos%5B2*x%5D%29%5E11%2Cx%5D)) in terms of elementary trigonometric functions.

Computing
$$S_p=\sum_{n=0}^p \frac{4^{n+1}}{2n+1} \int_0^{\frac \pi 2}\Bigg[\frac{ \sin ^2(t)}{5-\cos (2 t)}\Bigg]^{2n+1}dt$$ it looks better to write it as
$$S_p=-\sqrt{\pi }\,\,\sum_{n=0}^p \frac{\Gamma \left(2 n+\frac{3}{2}\right)}{\Gamma (2 n+2)}\,B_{-\frac{1}{2}}\left(2 n+1,-2 n-\frac{1}{2}\right)$$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 p & S_p \\
 0 & 0.5764929933 \\
 1 & 0.5905254035 \\
 2 & 0.5912752808 \\
 3 & 0.5913264052 \\
 4 & 0.5913303391 \\
 5 & 0.5913306647 \\
 6 & 0.5913306929 \\
 7 & 0.5913306955 \\
 8 & 0.5913306957
\end{array}
\right)$$
The last value in the table is
$$S_8=\left(\frac{1593269}{765765}-\frac{2025528882598026950447}{436968810224560373760
   \sqrt{6}}\right) \pi$$ (error= $2.45\times 10^{-11}$).

The next one
$$S_9=\left(\frac{31037876}{14549535}-\frac{8543966267760579986943883}{179331999716159577
   3911040 \sqrt{6}}\right) \pi$$ (error= $2.35\times 10^{-12}$).

This fast convergence is explained by the fact that, for large $n$
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{(4 n+3) (4 n+5)}{8 (n+1) (2 n+3)}\frac{B_{-\frac{1}{2}}\left(2 n+3,-2 n-\frac{5}{2}\right)}{B_{-\frac{1}{2}}\left(2
   n+1,-2 n-\frac{1}{2}\right)}\to \sim \frac 19$$

**Edit**

If this could help

$$I_n=\frac{4^{n+1}}{2n+1} \int_0^{x}\Bigg[\frac{ \sin ^2(t)}{5-\cos (2 t)}\Bigg]^{2n+1}dt$$ can write
$$I_n=\frac {z ^{4 n+3}}{4^n \,(2n+1)(4n+3)}F_1\left(2 n+\frac{3}{2};2 n+1,\frac{1}{2};2
   n+\frac{5}{2};-\frac{z^2}{2},z^2\right)$$ where $z=\sin(x)$ and $F_1(.)$ is the Appell hypergeometric function of two variables.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun. Better than an approximate, the nice exact solution :

[image]

Of course this isn't from a normal man. Thanks to WolframAlpha.

Comment: Yuck ! (*beurk* in French). Cheers :-)